# One click SQL server /IIS installation

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to distribute web application in asp.net / SQL server to end users, so they can install it on their machines locally). In order to do this I need them to install SQL server \ IIS, which seems overly complicated for end users. Any suggestions on how to do it best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Microsoft Web Platform Installer** makes it pretty easy to install IIS and SQL Server on your local machine. You would likely have to provide written instructions to get it and install them but it makes it pretty easy. Here is a link: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx